# Service IP & Port discovery with Kubernetes for external App

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dns

I'm creating an App that will have to communicate with a Kubernetes service, via REST APIs. The service hosts a docker image that's listening on port 8080 and responds with a JSON body.

I noticed that when I create a deployment via -

```
kubectl expose deployment myapp --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort --name=app-service
```

It then creates a service entitled *app-service*

To then locally test this, I obtain the IP:port for the created service via -

```
minikube service app-service --url
```

I'm using minikube for my local development efforts. I then get a response such as http://172.17.118.68:31970/ which then when I enter on my browser, works fine (I get the JSON responses i'm expecting).

However, it seems the IP & port for that service are always different whenever I start this service up.

Which leads to my question - how is a mobile App supposed to find that new IP:Port then if it's subject to change? Is the common way to work around this to register that combination via a DNS server (such as Google Cloud's DNS system?)

Or am I missing a step here with setting up Kubernetes public services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which leads to my question - how is a mobile App supposed to find that new IP:Port then if it's subject to change?

`minikube` is not meant for production use. It is only meant for development purpose. You should create a real kubernetes cluster and use [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) type service or an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)(for L7 traffic) to expose your service to external world. Since you need to expose your backend REST api, Ingress is good choice.

Comment: Let's assume I used Ingress and I got an external IP address for it. What's the recommended path to tie my app for finding that IP address? Should I use a DNS system that maps that IP address to a specific URL, and have my app call into that URL?

Comment: Yes. You need to host your backend on a domain you own. Then your app can connect to the backend using the fqdn. And yes this involves setting up the appropriate DNS entries.